# how to use $select with multiple parameters with API URL to select only specific columns?

Tags: php, api

I am using the API to retrieve some information. But my problem is that I don't want all the columns that are in there but just want only specific one's. Like "Description","StartDate","EndDate"etc.

And the below code is working fine if i just want to retrieve one column using $select:

```
$sdate=$_POST["Startdate"];
$edate=$_POST["Enddate"];
$Authorization= "Token: $result";                  
$ch = curl_init();                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ["Content-type:application/JSON",
     $Authorization]);
$api_request_parameter1 = ['search'=>"StartDate gt DateTime'$sdate' and StartDate le DateTime'$edate'"];
$api_request_parameter7 = ['$orderby'=>"Description"];
$api_request_parameter2 = array('$select'=>"Description");
//$api_request_parameter3 = ['$select'=>"StartDate"];
//$api_request_parameter4 = ['$select'=>"EndDate"];
//$api_request_parameter5 = ['$select'=>"StaerTime"];
//$api_request_parameter6 = ['$select'=>"EndTime"];
//$api_request_parameter2 = array('select'=>"");
$api_request_url = "...../api/v1/Events/10";
$api_request_url .= "?".http_build_query($api_request_parameter1).http_build_query($api_request_parameter2).http_build_query($api_request_parameter7);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_request_url);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo $response;
```

I have tried to select multiple column using

```
$api_request_url .= "?".http_build_query($api_request_parameter1).http_build_query($api_request_parameter2).http_build_query($api_request_parameter3).http_build_query($api_request_parameter7);
```

But not succeeded.

Can you please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: If the API supports the feature to filter the return values then you can, otherwise you cant

Comment: It supports but I can only make it with just one column and not multiple

Comment: That's an API specific problem, does it's provider offer any support?

Comment: Yes, but first I want to check if my code for selecting multiple column is right or not?

Comment: You have to check with API's doc, it will specify how you fetch data. We can't tell since you don't give us the details about the API.

Comment: code for $select given in official document in cURL is as follows: https://yourv20URL/api/v1/events/10?search=EventID eq 5708$select=Description,StartDate,EndDate. but I dont know how to execute in php curl